# Retrieving image from sqlite database java

Tags: java, database, image, sqlite

Trying to retrieve stored images from sqlite database but don't seem to be having any luck. My code:

```
int i = 0;
while (resultSet.next()) {
    InputStream in = resultSet.getBinaryStream(1);
    OutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File("PeoplesInfo"+i+".jpg"));
    i++;
    int c = 0;
    while ((c = in.read()) > -1) {
        f.write(c);
    }
    f.close();
    in.close();
}
```

The errors which i'm getting are:

```
java.sql.SQLException: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver
at org.sqlite.Unused.unused(Unused.java:29)
at org.sqlite.Unused.getBinaryStream(Unused.java:92)
at Database.main(Database.java:50)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQLite JDBC implementation you're using doesn't implement `getBinaryStream`.

You'll need to use the `getBytes` method instead.